# spyder cant load tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, tensorflow, spyder

I build and installed tensorflow in my ubuntu 16.04 with gpu. In command line I can easily activate tensorflow environment but while I try to run the code through spyder it show this : "No module named tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist"

how can I run my python code from spyder with tensorflow?

Answer (score 2):

1. Enter the enviornment

   `source activate tensorflow`
2. install spyder

   `conda install spyder`
3. Run spyder

   `spyder`

`