# Why does the 'tensorflow' module import fail in Spyder and not in Jupyter Notebook and not in Python prompt?

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, environment, spyder

I have not used Linux/Unix for more a decade. Why does the 'tensorflow' module import fail in Spyder and not in Jupyter Notebook and not in Python prompt?

**SCENARIO:**

- [terminal] spyder
- [spyder][IPython console] Type 'import tensorflow as tf' in the IPython console

**CURRENT RESULT:**

- [spyder][IPython console] Message error: 'ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow''

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:**

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04 (VMWare)
- Python: Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)
- Install of TensorFlow:

  - [terminal] sudo -s
  - [terminal] conda create --name=IntroToTensorFlow python=3 anaconda
  - [terminal] source activate IntroToTensorFlow
  - [terminal] conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
- PATH = $PATH:/home/mo/anaconda3/envs/IntroToTensorFlow/bin

**COMMENTS:**

- When I replay the following scenario, it works fine:

  - [terminal] sudo -s
  - [terminal] source activate IntroToTensorFlow
  - [terminal] python
  - [python] import tensorflow as tf
- When I replay the tensorflow import in Jupyter Notebook, it works fine too

**WHAT I HAVE DONE SO FAR:**

- I Googled it but I did not find a suitable anwser
- I searched in the Stack Overflow questions

Comment: Note: if you want to render a formatted code block inside a list item, use double indent (8 spaces instead of 4).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This might be a matter of environment variables. Try the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40166386/spyder-cant-load-tensorflow) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41344017/why-does-the-tensorflow-module-import-fail-in-spyder-and-not-in-jupyter-notebo):

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64
CUDA_PATH=/usr/local/cuda

Comment: Should I then reinstall spyder after sourcing the tensorflow environment?

Comment: Why should I specify lib from cuda? Does it mean that I have to install CUDA before installing tensorFlow?

Comment: Thx you for having taken time to share a comments.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

It is solved: I reinstalled spyder and it works properly now. Thank you.